# How to pull image from web using its source

Tags: html, imagesource

I've just started learning how to code starting with HTML. I'm using Codepen and when I add any image it refuses to populate. I can see on the page where it shows my alt text and the image load fail icon, so I'm confident I've coded it correctly. Can you not just pull any image off the web using it's source? Is there some library of widely available images that I can use? Just a little confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In response to your doubts

**Can you not just pull any image off the web using it's source?**
*If it is possible to locate images directly from the internet, but you have to be careful to have the consent for the use of it*

**Is there some library of widely available images that I can use?**
*There are several portals where to locate images of different categories, some images are paid, others are free, to mention one you have pexels.com,
Next I leave you an example of the code looking for an image in this portal*

```html
<img
src = "https://images.pexels.com/photos/374631/pexels-photo-374631.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500"
alt = "Image"
width = '250px'
>
```

I hope I have been able to help you

Best regards